# data from database not updating after deploying

Tags: typescript, next.js

I deployed my next js site using vercel, the site contains a functions were i can add, get, edit and delete data from mongodb, all the functions works great locally but after deploying I noticed while I can add, get, edit and delete data normally the browser only shows the old data that I added pre deploying and doesn't show the new data that I added after deploying.

all the functions work great and I can see the changes in the database but I don't see the new changes on screen.

what could be the problem ?

```
const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = useState([]);

// fetch all projects
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProjects = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/project", {
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setAllProjects(data);
    };

    fetchProjects();
  }, []);

  console.log("allProjects: ", allProjects);
```

this is the api route

/api/project/route.ts

```
export const GET = async (req) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    const projectSchema = await Projects.find({}).populate("_id");
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(projectSchema), { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    new Response("Failed to fech Project", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

Comment: code or anything that can help in identifyoing the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your API HTTP request headears

```
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
```

your browser cache your request responses. You need to block that.

Comment: do i need to add this only to the fetch or to the post and patch and delete also ?

Comment: You can add all request headers. @alifares

Comment: it didn't work @SefaUn

Comment: did you check your network of browser console ? network size of items can not be `memory cache`. @alifares

Comment: i have the same fetch in another component that works great, its just this specific fetch

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `projects` state to the dependency array to rerender the page with the new changes of the `project` state whenever the state changes. Also, I highly recommend using `react-query` instead of `useFetch` it will fit what you need exactly especially with the `loading, error` state it will help you a lot.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProjects = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/project", {
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setAllProjects(data);
    };

    fetchProjects();
  }, [projects]);

  console.log("allProjects: ", allProjects);
```

notice if the `projects` is an object you need to use `useMemo` hook to ensure the reference of the object is something like that:

```
const cachedProjects = useMemo(() =>({projects}), [projects])
useEffect(()=>{
// same code as the above
}, [cachedProjects])
```

Comment: tried it didnt work, im going to try react-query to see if anything changes

Comment: is the API you used there depending on page number or something like that?

Comment: could you please, show the whole state to help you properly?

Comment: no the api route is not dynamic, i have dynamic api routes and they work great because they have no cache, its just this specific route that does not update